# Pedagogic Notes on graviton self-energy 1-loop Calculation

Tags: resource-recommendations, feynman-diagrams, quantum-gravity, perturbation-theory, self-energy

Any lecture notes on graviton self-energy 1-loop calculation would be appreciated.
A detailed account of how to calculate the vertices of three gravitons, how to assign the momenta with signs to the legs, how to permute momenta over the legs, and how to incorporate the symmetry factor, also a pedagogic derivation of its amplitude would be appreciated. Any reference about such calculation?